# Match pattern within pattern

Tags: php, regex, dom

I'm trying to match any bracketed items within `<sup>` tags.

My regular expression is being too greedy, starting with the first `<sup>` tag and ending at the last `</sup>` tag.

```
/<sup\b[^>]*>(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)<\/sup>/
```

Example html:

```
<sup>[this should be gone]</sup>
<sup>but this should stay</sup>
<sup>this should [ also stay</sup>
[and this as well]
<sup><a href="#">[but this should definitely go]</a></sup>
```

Any idea why?

Thanks!

EDIT: I suppose these answers make sense.  I've got much of the HTML parsed without regex; I just figured that this particular example would work with regex because it would do the following:

1. see the first `<sup>` tag
2. find the first instance of `</sup>`
3. search the inside for (wild)(bracket)(wild)(closing bracket)(wild)

Comment: Which cases is it working on? Which is it failing on? "Too greedy" isn't quite enough information :)

Comment: "starting with the first `<sup>` tag and ending at the last `</sup>` tag"  Meaning that it would take the whole document in this case (untested on this particular example)

Comment: I'd suggest using a DOM parser to parse XML as regular expressions are not well suited to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do this.  [It's impossible to parse HTMl with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), because regular expressions can only match regular languages; these languages are a simpler subset of the actual languages we use.  One very common *non*-regular language is the Dyck language of balanced brackets; it's impossible to match correctly nested parentheses with regular expressions.  And HTML, if you think about it, is the same as this, with tags replacing parentheses.  Thus, matching (a) correctly nested `sup` tags is impossible, and (b) matching balanced braces is impossible.  I don't use PHP myself, but I know it has access to an HTML DOM; I'd recommend using that instead.  Then, filter through that for every `sup` tag, and check each one's inner text.  If you only want to catch tags whose inner text is just `[...]`, where the `...` does not contain square brackets, you can use `^\[[^\]]+\]$` as your regex; if you want real nesting, more complicated checking is necessary.

Comment: LOL.  That's a fantastic link.

Comment: :P I've seen the link.  I didn't really consider the query to be serious xhtml parsing (as I'm just matching a single tag), but perhaps the nested tags do indeed qualify it as the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement was to specifically remove any text inside "`<sup>[`" and "`]</sup`>", then you would be ok. But by your last example, you want to account for a nested tag as well, and probably arbitrary nested tags. So therefore I must remind you...

[Don't parse html with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the normal behavior? Have you [specified the ungreedy option](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for your regexp?

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do this with one regular expression. You will need one that replaces using a callback function, which will run a separate regular expression.

the better method as everyone has mentioned would be to use a DOM object to parse the HTML first.

Answer (score 0):

using regexp to parse html is usually not a very good idea.

see [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)